# Redis - node.js / ping or alive call

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to check if the connection to my redis DB is alive.

I want to do it with node.js - Every 5 minutes send a call to DB redis, and if the connection is lost, notify it.

I use the following:

```
var db = require("redis");
var dbclient = db.createClient();
```

The problem is that I don't see and alive/ping command which supported by this package.

Comment: Which package do you use?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using events that the client already provides:

```
var redis  = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();

client.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Redis ready');
}).on('error', function(err) {
  // You should assume here that the connection is lost, or compromised.
  console.log('Redis error', err);
  ...
});
```

The `error` event will trigger regardless of whether a command it sent or not.

Answer (score 0):

Complete example:

```
const redis = require('redis')
const client = redis.createClient();

client
    .on('ready', () => console.log('Connected to Redis.'))
    .on('error', err => console.error('Redis error', err));

client.connect().then(() => {

    client.ping().then(response => console.log(response));

    client.set('foo', 'boo').then(response => console.log(response));
    client.get('foo').then(value => console.log(`Value retrieved from Redis: ${value}`));    

    client.set('score', 0).then(response => console.log(response));
    client.incr('score').then(response => console.log(response));
    client.incrBy('score', 10).then(response => console.log(response));
    client.get('score').then(value => console.log(`Score retrieved from Redis: ${value}`));    

});
```